# Trying to find the state where the most popular item was sold SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Having a really hard time actually getting numbers I need. 
I need to project the state where the most stoves are sold.

I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 C.StateProvince,
       COUNT(*) AS TimesSold
FROM CUSTOMER C 
INNER JOIN INVOICE I ON C.CustomerID = I.FK_CustomerID
INNER JOIN INV_LINE_ITEM L ON I.InvoiceNbr = L.FK_InvoiceNbr
FULL OUTER JOIN STOVE S ON S.SerialNumber = L.FK_StoveNbr
GROUP BY C.StateProvince, L.FK_StoveNbr
ORDER BY TimesSold DESC;
```

My output I am getting is:

```
State  Count
------ -----
OR      20
MT      16
```

But the output I need is:

```
State  Count
------ -----
OR      20
CO      9
```

Which leads me to believe I am not counting the right thing.

Data includes:

```
CUSTOMER (CustomerID, Name, StreetAddress, ApartmentNbr, City, 
          StateProvince, Zipcode, Country)

INVOICE (InvoiceNbr, InvoiceDt, TotalPrice, FK_CustomerID, FK_EmpID)

EMPLOYEE (EmpID, Name, Title, Initials)

INV_LINE_ITEM (LineNbr, Quantity, FK_InvoiceNbr, FK_PartNbr, 
               FK_StoveNbr, ExtendedPrice)

STOVE (SerialNumber, Type, Version, DateOfManufacture, Color, FK_EmpID)
```

Comment: The actual ddl is much better then making us guess. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Do you really have a separate table for each type of item you sell? And if you want to limit this to stoves it would make more sense to have an INNER join instead of a full outer join.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` counts rows; you have an OUTER JOIN so perhaps you need `COUNT(column_name)` where the value of column_name can be NULL (and hence, not counted with `COUNT(column_name)`

Answer (score 0):

{Knee-jerk reaction}  Change this

ORDER BY TimesSold DESC;

to this

ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;

Comment: This is the same thing. They are ordering by the alias provided to the SUM. And if the values returned there are 20, 16 and 9 this wouldn't produce the results of 20 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 C.StateProvince, COUNT(*) AS TimesSold
FROM CUSTOMER C INNER JOIN
     INVOICE I
     ON C.CustomerID = I.FK_CustomerID INNER JOIN
     INV_LINE_ITEM L
     ON I.InvoiceNbr = L.FK_InvoiceNbr INNER JOIN
     STOVE S
     ON S.SerialNumber = L.FK_StoveNbr
GROUP BY C.StateProvince
ORDER BY TimesSold DESC;
```

I think the problem is the `GROUP BY`.  However, the `FULL OUTER JOIN` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is just you query formatted
Need to use distinct is a clear indication of a problem
That full outer join on stove does nothing - if SerialNumber is not unique it could break stuff
Always report the group by columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 
       C.StateProvince, COUNT(*) AS TimesSold
FROM CUSTOMER C 
INNER JOIN INVOICE I 
   ON C.CustomerID = I.FK_CustomerID
INNER JOIN INV_LINE_ITEM L 
   ON I.InvoiceNbr = L.FK_InvoiceNbr
FULL OUTER JOIN STOVE S 
   ON S.SerialNumber = L.FK_StoveNbr
GROUP BY C.StateProvince, L.FK_StoveNbr
ORDER BY TimesSold DESC;
```

If you run this you should see your problem

```
SELECT C.StateProvince, L.FK_StoveNbr, COUNT(*) AS TimesSold
FROM CUSTOMER C 
INNER JOIN INVOICE I 
   ON C.CustomerID = I.FK_CustomerID
INNER JOIN INV_LINE_ITEM L 
   ON I.InvoiceNbr = L.FK_InvoiceNbr
GROUP BY C.StateProvince, L.FK_StoveNbr
ORDER BY C.StateProvince, L.FK_StoveNbr;
```

If the join to stoves was to find stoves only then do that as an inner join.